# How to pass to URLSession.shared.dataTask called in a loop?

Tags: ios, swift, loops, core-data, urlsession

I am downloading image from server and when image is downloaded I have to save that image in coredata with id. Here is the code

```
for actionDict:JSON in actionData
  {
    if(actionDict["ProtocolImage"].stringValue.isValidURL())
      {
          URLSession.shared.sessionDescription = "\(actionDict["Id"].intValue)"
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: actionDict["ProtocolImage"].stringValue)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                if data != nil{
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    if image != nil{                       
                       ProtocolActionModel.updateValueWhere(id: Int64(URLSession.shared.sessionDescription!)!, key: "protocolImage", value:( UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)! as NSData))
                    }
                }
            }).resume()
      }
  }
```

`(actionDict["Id"].intValue` is id associated with image that I want to save in coredata with image but when I save it is always set to last item id of for loop.

**`actionData`** is

```
{
    data =     (
                {
            CheckDesc = vcnhfgb;
            CheckName = hjnhfnmjh;
            CheckedImage =             (
            );
            CreatedDate = "/Date(1487201399293)/";
            Id = 3;
            IsChecked = 0;
            ProtocolId = 4;
            ProtocolImage = "http://example.com/ApplicationImages/522cb086-0b0d-4ad9-b5ae-79f6f9a9fbf2.jpg";
            Sorting = "<null>";
        },
                {
            CheckDesc = bfghrthbn;
            CheckName = ddfgb;
            CheckedImage =             (
            );
            CreatedDate = "/Date(1499167861457)/";
            Id = 71;
            IsChecked = 0;
            ProtocolId = 4;
            ProtocolImage = "http://example.com/ApplicationImages/860e68e4-187c-4e49-a936-088c97c500b2.png";
            Sorting = 41;
        },
                {
            CheckDesc = bnvbncyh;
            CheckName = nbnyhjhg;
            CheckedImage =             (
            );
            CreatedDate = "/Date(1499167894280)/";
            Id = 72;
            IsChecked = 0;
            ProtocolId = 4;
            ProtocolImage = "http://example.com/ApplicationImages/e4311494-27ad-4d12-958b-68e0c705a94d.png";
            Sorting = 42;
        },
                {
            CheckDesc = hjbnvbytuu;
            CheckName = nmnmhjgh;
            CheckedImage =             (
            );
            CreatedDate = "/Date(1499167918147)/";
            Id = 73;
            IsChecked = 0;
            ProtocolId = 4;
            ProtocolImage = "http://example.com/ApplicationImages/15ac0300-8877-4503-8c6d-957b5248e829.png";
            Sorting = 43;
        },
                {
            CheckDesc = "";
            CheckName = tyres;
            CheckedImage =             (
            );
            CreatedDate = "/Date(1499172466890)/";
            Id = 74;
            IsChecked = 0;
            ProtocolId = 4;
            ProtocolImage = "<null>";
            Sorting = 44;
        }
    );
    message = success;
    status = 1;
}
```

reponse

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600000634720> { URL: http://example/ApplicationImages/860e68e4-187c-4e49-a936-088c97c500b2.png } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    "Content-Length" = 254882;
    "Content-Type" = "image/png";
    Date = "Wed, 05 Jul 2017 05:31:46 GMT";
    Etag = "\"e09aa43b9f4d21:0\"";
    "Last-Modified" = "Tue, 04 Jul 2017 11:31:01 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
    "X-Powered-By-Plesk" = PleskWin;
} }
```

Please provide any solution that will solve my problem.

Comment: `(actionDict["Id"].intValue` is same for all images?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni no all are different

Comment: reason could be your for loop end up running before data is save to the database. And hence the reference is set to the last value of the loop. Debug it and check.

Comment: @Gihan image downloading takes time and so loop must continue requesting download other images

Comment: Yes but I guess the loop still run firing all async method calls to dataTask 
 and before any of the completions are called. since URLSession.shared.sessionDescription = "\(actionDict["Id"].intValue)" is out side the dataTask method it has finished running for all before the first completion is called to save the image.

Comment: Yes you are right, I know `URLSession.shared.sessionDescription = "\(actionDict["Id"].intValue)"` this line not correct thats why I am asking how to pass variable to datatask correctly and what is the solution for this ?

Comment: what is in your response object ?

Comment: So what you could do is maintain dictionary keeping the URL as your key and "\(actionDict["Id"].intValue)" as the object and access it inside for the real value

Comment: @VarunNaharia check my answer it's easy way to download image from url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not compiled this hope you can get the idea. Assuming URL is unique to ID you can keep it as a key and access it inside the completion handler.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

var keyDictionary = [String: Int]()
for actionDict:JSON in actionData
{
    if(actionDict["ProtocolImage"].stringValue.isValidURL())
    {
        keyDictionary[actionDict["ProtocolImage"].stringValue] = actionDict["Id"].intValue
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: actionDict["ProtocolImage"].stringValue)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if data != nil{
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                if image != nil{
                    realValue = keyDictionary[response.URL];
                    ProtocolActionModel.updateValueWhere(id: Int64(realvalue!)!, key: "protocolImage", value:( UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)! as NSData))
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `URLSession.shared.dataTask` i am using  `NSData(contentsOf: url as URL)` to download images from URL.

for eg:

I am just doing with static data replace it with dynamic

```
   var resultArray = [Dictionary<String,Any>]()
     var resultDict1 = Dictionary<String,Any>()
     resultDict1["Id"] = 3
     resultDict1["ProtocolImage"] = "https://alperkayabasi.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/asd.png"

     var resultDict2 = Dictionary<String,Any>()
     resultDict2["Id"] = 7
     resultDict2["ProtocolImage"] = "https://alperkayabasi.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/ios-simulator-screen-shot-08-oct-2014-16-39-03.png"

     var resultDict3 = Dictionary<String,Any>()
     resultDict3["Id"] = 9
     resultDict3["ProtocolImage"] = "https://alperkayabasi.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/screen-shot-2015-02-13-at-10-18-12.png"

     resultArray.append(contentsOf: [resultDict1,resultDict2,resultDict3])

     for actionDict in resultArray {
         //here check your URL is valid one
         if let url = URL(string: (actionDict["ProtocolImage"] as? String ?? "".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed))!) {

                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    // Background Thread
                    let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL)
                    if let data = imageData {
                        if let image = UIImage(data: data as Data) {
                            print(actionDict["Id"] as? Int ?? 0)
                            print(actionDict["ProtocolImage"] as? String ?? "")

                            //here itself you can able to save image to coredata
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                //update UI part if requires
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The output :

here you will get correct id for image.

```
7
https://alperkayabasi.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/ios-simulator-screen-shot-08-oct-2014-16-39-03.png
9
https://alperkayabasi.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/screen-shot-2015-02-13-at-10-18-12.png
3
https://alperkayabasi.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/asd.png
```

Comment: Up for your answer but Gihan answer has less changes to that I have to do in my code, so I choose that as correct

Comment: @VarunNaharia no worries i m just posting for alternative ways... glad to help